# Can't get the script to execute, chrome message passing error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to finish up this chrome extension I've been working on but I just got stuck.

Basically I'm trying to get the script to be executed when enabled by the user (by clicking an on and off switch I put in the popup window). Either I'm missing some code, or my chrome message passing is wonky at some point so popup cant communicate with content.

I'm a beginner, this is the first thing I've ever written, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code, let me know if you need to see anything else

**script.js**

```
    var audio = new Audio("http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_libwsrXYlA1qbma2vo1.mp3"),
    timer = null,
    isScrolling = false;


function enable() {
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        audio.play();
        if (!isScrolling) {
            isScrolling = true;
            setTimeout(function () {
                audio.pause();
                isScrolling = false;
            }, 600);
        }
    });
}

function disable() {
    $(window).off('scroll');
    if (!isScrolling) {
        isScrolling = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            audio.pause();
            isScrolling = false;
        }, 600);
    }
}

chrome.tabs.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
        if (request.greeting == "hello") {
            enable();
        } else {
            disable();


        }
    }
);
```

**popup.js**

```
    $('#myonoffswitch').on('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            console.log('enable');
        } else {
            console.log('disable');

        }

        chrome.tabs.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function (response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
        }); 
});
```

**mypopup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
    </div>

<script src="/data/script.js"></script>    
<script src="/data/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the question/problem you are having? Please be specific.

Comment: The script doesn't enable when I want it to. I want it to be enabled when the onoffswitch is set to on, and disabled when its set to off

Answer (score 1):

Your code does never goes to the disable branch in the content script:

```
    if (request.greeting == "hello") {
        enable();
    } else {
        disable();
    }
```

You *always* send `{greeting: "hello"}` regardless of off/on state.